# jQuery - how to get dynamic width of element according to class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have this basic animation which includes two divs. One div has a class of `single` the other div has a class of `double`. Each have a height of 39px.

`.single` elements have a width of 100px, and `.double` elements have a width of 200px, however, I start out with the `.single` div at 50px, and `.double` at 100px, and then, using jQuery, I (wish) to animate each div to the width according to it's class. It's a bit hard to explain, so I'll show you the code format:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="block" class="red single"></div>
<div id="block" class="blue double"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#block {
    display: block;
    height: 16px; /* animate to: 39px */
    background-color: #eee;
}

#block.red {
    background-color: red;
}

#block.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

#block.single {
    width: 50px; /* animate to: 100px */
}

#block.double {
    width: 100px; /* animate to: 200px */
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
    if($("#block").hasClass("double")) {
        respectiveWidth = "200px"
    }

    if($("#block").hasClass("single")) {
        respectiveWidth = "100px"
    }

    $("#block").delay(delayRate).animate({
        height: "145px",
        width: respectiveWidth
    }, 900);
```

I *would* just do as follows:

```
$("#block").animate({
    height: "39px"
});

$("#block.single").animate({
    width: "100px"
});

$("#block.single").animate({
    width: "200px"
});
```

But that animates `#block.single` before it animates `#block.double`, and I wish to animate them simultaneously.

Any help would be very much appreciated, I am ready to be done with this. Hehe.

Comment: It means that you should not use an ID for more than one element.

Comment: Ooh, I see. So could I use `if($("div").hasClass("...")) {...}`?

Comment: Yes, you can also add a class like _block_ to the DIV elements and select them using class selector. It doesn't solve the issue though.

Comment: No, that animates `id="block1` before it animates `id="block2"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs must be unique, you can use classes instead, try the following.

```
<div class="block red single"></div>
<div class="block blue double"></div>
```

```
$(".block").animate({
    height: "39px"
});

$(".block.single").animate({
    width: "100px"
}, 700);

$(".block.double").animate({
    width: "200px"
}, 700);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eCUf8/

Comment: Okay, this is better than what I was experiencing, but notice how it animates the height before it does the width of the two elements? I want it all to animate at the same time. I wonder if there's a method for this specifically, like have conditional statements _inside_ the width object, instead of using basic jQuery syntax, as it doesn't _really_ achieve what I wish to accomplish.

Comment: Or a conditional statement to dynamically add a respective width variable.

Comment: Ha Ha! Yes! Good god, that's so simple. I guess that's what happens when I work on something for too long. Thank you.